# Bootstrap Menu Change Active Class Change Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried several iterations of this, but can't seem to get my active class to change on a Bootstrap navbar (in Bootstrap 4).  When I click on a new menu option, it starts to change to the active class, but immediately changes back to having the 'home' option as active.

Here is my navbar:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item btn-group">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Deals
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

and my js code:

```
 <script>
            $(".navbar-nav li").on("click", function(){
            $(".navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any custom JavaScript. The bootstrap.js is all you need (along with jQuery).

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use the "wheels" that are already there.

The following 3 files is what you need to load (in that order):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Your navbar is also missing some other parts described in the docs here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: hmm..i guess I'll have to re-investigate, because for some reason it isn't working on my site

Comment: Your navbar is also missing some other parts described in the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/